# Why does np False and boolean False act differently

Tags: python-3.x, boolean, missing-data

I am working on a project and I am attempting to create a `dataframe` that returns 1 if a value is there and 0 if it is a nan entry.

Here is what I have so far...

```
used=np.isnan(user_user)
used=used.replace(to_replace={False:1, True:0})
```

This is the [clip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3bBG.png) of the original frame

After the first line of code is run I get this [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99LGG.png).

And after the last line, I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGYAS.png)

What is happening here? I realize that the False in the `dataframe` is type `numpy.bool_` and a normal False is type `bool` but I cannot use the is operator here so is there a way to directly access the `numpy.bool_` and make this work or is there a better function which can get the result I am looking for?

Comment: Why not just use `df.notnull()`?

Comment: Because I am foolish. Thanks